# Firebase FCM error: "results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}"

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push

> "{"multicast_id":2590279481594016535,
> "success":0,
> "failure":1,
> "canonical_ids":0,
> "results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}"

this Error i am getting, below is the code.

```
$deviceToken = Str::random(60);

// Store the device token in the user's record
$user->forceFill([
    'device_token' => $deviceToken,
])->save();

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: key=SERVER_KEY',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$data = array(
    "to" => $token,
    "notification" => array(
        "title" => 'Login successful',
        "body" => 'You have successfully logged in.',
        "sound" => 'default'
    )
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if ($result === FALSE) {
    die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
}

curl_close($ch);
```

This is the correct way to pass the token.

Comment: does your `$token` has any value?

Comment: This error probably means that you're trying to send an invalid token, but we can't say for sure. We need to see the data you're trying to send.
In general, this error means that the token to which you're trying to send the message is either invalid, no longer exists, or it belongs to another Firebase project.